# SQL return selected result to EF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

In Entity Framework, I tried executing these two queries:

Query #1:

```
var deptInput = new SqlParameter("@DepartmentName", deptString);
var departmentTable = Database.Users.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.
[ViewEmployeeListByDepartment] @DepartmentName", deptInput).ToList();
```

Query #2:

```
var deptInput = new SqlParameter("@DepartmentName", deptString);
var departmentTable = Database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXECUTE dbo.
[ViewEmployeeListByDepartment] @DepartmentName", deptInput);
```

And this is my stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
Declare @CounterForEmployees int
Declare @NumberOfEmployees int
Declare @TableCount int = 1

Declare @DepartmentTable TABLE(
    Id nvarchar(450),
    UserName nvarchar(256),
    Display_Name nvarchar(256),
    Direct_Supervisor nvarchar(256),
    Ranking int 
);

SET @NumberOfEmployees = (SELECT Count(*) 
                          FROM dbo.[User]
                          WHERE Department = @DepartmentName)
SET @CounterForEmployees = 0

--Get the HOD of the Department First
INSERT INTO @DepartmentTable
    SELECT 
        Id, UserName, Display_Name, Direct_Supervisor, ''  
    FROM 
        [ASEAppraisalDB].[dbo].[User]
    WHERE
        Department = @DepartmentName AND 
        UserName IN (SELECT Distinct(Head_Of_Department)
                     FROM [ASEAppraisalDB].[dbo].[User]
                     WHERE Department = @DepartmentName)

UPDATE @DepartmentTable 
SET Ranking = @TableCount 
WHERE Ranking = 0
.
. 
.
.
.
.
. 
.
SELECT * FROM @DepartmentTable
```

When I execute the first one, it returns a error message saying there is missing column from the `dbo.[User]` table inside `@DepartmentTable`. The `dbo.[User]` table has some columns I did not select into `@DepartmentTable`.

When I execute the second one, it returns only a number (which is the number of employees). It seems that the second query has only selected the part that counts the employee. The number of employee is only needed for my other parts of my code for calculations for a while loop. I do not need to return it to the EF.

I only want the result from `select * from @DepartmentTable` to be returned to Entity Framework. In the parameter of the stored procedure in SQL Server Object Explorer, it also says that it returns integer shown below:

[image]

How do I fix this? Also Which query is more efficient and more 'correct' to use?

Comment: It's Not Related to EF it's Return interger is only for SQL Stored Procedure.

Comment: First You can check the Result in sql server. after it's work fine in ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you map you stored procedure to your .edmx fle in enfity framework create a complex type. 
[image: Like this]

first click on Generate column Information then click on Create New Complex Type

I will be yielding the result from complex type.
Since i am using a repository pattern i have created a generic function for executing stored procedure in my code which takes name of stored procedure as string and list of sql parameter.

```
public List<T> ExecuteStoredProc(string StoredProcName, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        List<T> list = null;
        try
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StoredProcName))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("Exec ");
                sb.Append(StoredProcName);

                foreach (SqlParameter item in parameters)
                {
                    if (list == null)
                    {
                        sb.Append(" @");
                        list = new List<T>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(", @");
                    }
                    sb.Append(item.ParameterName);
                    if (item.Direction == System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output)
                    {
                        sb.Append(" OUT");
                    }
                }

                list = Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sb.ToString(), parameters.Cast<object>().ToArray()).ToList();
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //RAISERROR() has limitation of 255 characters, so complete error message is being passed through output parameter : @ErrorMessage
            if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
            {
                SqlParameter param = parameters.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output && a.ParameterName == Constants.Constant.ParamErrorMessage);
                if (param != null)
                {
                    string errorMessage = Convert.ToString(param.Value);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
                    {
                        throw new JcomSqlException(errorMessage, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new JcomSqlException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        return list;
    }

    Then use it with your repository 

       List<GetDepartmentDetails_Result> getDepts(string deptName)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> spm = new List<SqlParameter>()
        {
            new SqlParameter() { ParameterName="@DepartmentName", Value=deptName}
        };
        var result = this.UnitOfWork.GetRepository<GetDepartmentDetails_Result>().ExecuteStoredProc("GetDepartmentDetails", spm);
        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

All stored procedures return an `integer` only.It also return the data for multiple data tables.

You check in SQL Server when you execute stored procedure it's return two set of data table in SQL Server optionally returns int.

You can verify this Link [RETURN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql)

Comment: The integer returned from a stored procedure is used to indicate success or failure of the stored procedure.  By convention, procedures return 0 for success, and any other number for failure.  New code should always use errors and try/catch to determine success or failure instead, and should never pass data using the return value of a stored procedure.